# ¿Como creo un array apartir de mi array, que con .select cree un array con los elementos que empiecen con la letra p?

Tags: ruby

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
nombres = ["Violeta", "Andino", "Clemente", "Javiera", "Paula", "Pia", "Ray"]
a = nombres.select{ |ele|}
```

Quisiera saber cual sería la instrucción para crear en la variable `a` un `array` diferente que contenga solo los elementos que empiecen con la **letra P**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar el método `start_with?` junto con `select`:

```
a = nombres.select { |nombre| nombre.start_with?("P") }
#=> ["Paula", "Pia"]
```

Si quieres que ignore si es mayúscula o minúscula, podrías convertir todo a minúsculas (o mayúsculas) primero; por ejemplo:

```
a = nombres.select { |nombre| nombre.dwoncase.start_with?("p") }
#=> ["Paula", "Pia"]
```

O también podrías utilizar *regexp*:

```
a = nombres.select { |nombre| nombre.match?(/^p/i) }
#=> ["Paula", "Pia"]
```